# Помогите решить элементарную задачу по циклам с использованием for

Tags: javascript, циклы, frontend, for

Все мы любим развлекаться на свадьбе. Однажды ведущий придумал конкурс, где люди выстраиваются в линию и выпивают, но по определенным правилам. Каждый должен выпить количество рюмок, что соответствует его месту в очереди. Первый выпивает 1 стакан, второй - 2, третий - 3 и т.д. Помоги ведущему подготовить необходимое количество рюмок, чтобы гости не ждали!

примеры:

```
getDrinks (3) === 6 (1 + 2 + 3);
getDrinks (0) === 0 Нет гостей - нету выпивки;
getDrinks (5) === 15 (1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5);
```

Можете пожалуйста с объяснением, что откуда взяли
Спасибо большое!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я не понял, что должны выпивать гости, - рюмки или стаканы?

```js
function countOfShots(n) {
  return (n + 1) * n / 2;
}

console.log(0, countOfShots(0));
console.log(3, countOfShots(3));
console.log(5, countOfShots(5));
```

Comment: Спасибо, но мне бы решить именно через for)))

Comment: @oaleksandrovva https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration

Comment: @oaleksandrovva Вы вообще про цикл `for` ничего не знаете?

Comment: учу сейчас циклы, знаю как элементарные вещи делать, типа выбирать четные числа и т.п. Не понимаю как в этой задаче привязать сумму

Comment: пока вот что получила, и оно совсем не верно function getDrinks(guests) {
 const sum = 1;

  for (let i = 0; i >= guests; i++) {
    sum += i;
  }

  return sum;
}

Comment: @oaleksandrovva `let sum = 0; for (let i = 1; i <= guests; i++) { sum += i; } return sum;`

Comment: Работает, спасибо! а можете объяснить почему i = 1, а sum =0?

Comment: @oaleksandrovva Потому что в начале количество посчитанных рюмок равно нулю, а для счета гостей используются натуральные числа.

Comment: спасибо поняла, а почему правильно i<=guests, а не наоборот?

Comment: @oaleksandrovva, наоборот тоже правильно: `guests>=i`, только так никто не пишет.

Comment: смешно))) имею ввиду почему не верно i >= guests в данном случае :)

Comment: @oaleksandrovva Потому что это условие выполнения очередной итерации цикла. Попробуйте произнести это условие вслух.

Answer (score 0):

```
function getDrinks(numberOfGuests) {
  let sum = 0;
 
  for (let i = 1; i <= guests; i++) {
    sum += i;
  }
 
  return sum;
}
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]